# jQuery: Using replaceWith function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to replace a jQuery function in side script tag. I have this jQuery function in my layout just before the `</body>` tag.

```
<div id="white_backstretch">
  <script>
     $.backstretch("/body-bg.jpg");
  </script>
</div>
```

On another page (show page) I have:

```
<script>
  $('#white_backstretch').replaceWith("<script>" + $.backstretch(<%= @white_label.logo %> + "</script>");
</script>
```

Here I am trying to replace the existing

```
<script>$.backstretch("/body-bg.jpg");</script>
```

with

```
<script>$.backstretch(<%= @profile.logo %></script>
```

so that when different page come the background image will change. But the problem I am facing is:

```
<script>
  $('#white_backstretch').replaceWith("<script>" +     $.backstretch(/uploads/white/logo/4/image14.png) + "</script>");
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

First end `</script>` tag inside replace function is taken as end of the script so ");" <-- thrown as unexpected token error

So, it will be help full if any one tell me how to replace a jQuery method inside a script tag with another jQuery method? (this method should also be inside script tag since I want to use replaceWith jQuery method inside a html file)

Answer (score 1):

`$.replaceWith` will just replace and not execute the javascript. Even if you are able to get it working, it will be of no use.

I suggest you do this another way, by using function overriding

```
<div id="white_backstretch">
  <script>
      function replace() {
          $.backstretch("/body-bg.jpg");
      }         
  </script>
</div>
```

And in your show page

```
document.write("<script>function replace(){$.backstretch("<%= @profile.logo %>");} </script>")
```

and call `replace()` in page load or whereever it is appropriate.